# Save generated file link

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Ive created an action that uploads a file and generates a link for the file, I cant seem to figure out how to save the path name for another part of my controller to use, does anybody have any suggestions? here the code that generates the filepath/uploads the document.

```
 [HttpPost("UploadFiles")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> FileUpload(List<IFormFile> files)
    {
        var webroot = _env.WebRootPath;
        long size = files.Sum(f => f.Length);
        var filePaths = new List<string>();
        foreach (var formFile in files)
        {
            if(formFile.Length > 0)
            {
                var filePath = Path.Combine(/*AppContext.BaseDirectory*/webroot, $"{Guid.NewGuid().ToString()}.csv"); /*Path.GetTempPath()+ Guid.NewGuid().ToString()+".txt";*/
                filePaths.Add(filePath);


                using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
                {
                    await formFile.CopyToAsync(stream);                        

                }
            }
        }
        return Ok(new { count = files.Count, size, filePaths });
```

any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `TempData` or `Session` in this situation.

Usuage:

```
Tempdata["filePaths"]= filePaths;
```

or

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["filePaths"] = filePaths;
```